# ¿Cómo le hago un push_back a un array bidimensional ya definido?

Tags: c++, array

```
#include < iostream >
#include < vector >
#include < utility >

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int A[6][6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <6; j++){
            A[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    A[0][1] = 1;
    A[0][3] = 1;
    A[1][2] = 1;
    A[1][4] = 1;
    A[2][4] = 1;
    A[3][1] = 1;
    A[4][3] = 1;
    A[4][5] = 1;
    A[5][2] = 1;

    vector< vector< int > >;
    A.push_back( vector<int>() );
    A[0].push_back(1);
}
```

Estoy intentando hacer una matriz de adyacencia de un grafo, este código me lo proporcionó un profesor, pero me da muchos errores y nunca antes había trabajado con vector< vector< int > >, los errores que me da son los siguientes:

- 26   2 [Error] declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
- 27   7 [Error] request for member 'push_back' in 'A[0]', which is of non-class type 'int [6]'

Por sus respuestas, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Primero los errores:
El primer error: te falta darle el nombre al vector, literalmente el error dice que la declaracion no esta declarando nada, y es cierto:
- `vector< vector< int > >;` es solo la clase de la variable.
- Deberias escribir algo como `vector< vector< int > > miVector;` Para crear un vector de vectores(*ver nota*), que se llame `miVector`.
El segundo error: sucede porque la variable `A` es del tipo `int[][]`( vector bidimensional de numeros enteros ) por lo cual al hacer `A.push_back(0)` estas tratando de invocar el metodo `push_back` de un `int[][]`, el cual es un tipo de datos nativo, que no posee metodos.
El metodo `push_back` le pertenece a la clase `vector`, por lo que deberia quedarte algo asi:

```
vector< vector< int > > miVector;

miVector.push_back( vector<int>() );

miVector[0].push_back(1);
```

¿Que esta pasando aca?
La clase vector es un template, crea un vector del tipo de datos que se le diga, entonces si vos instancias un `vector<int>` crearas un arreglo de enteros, y si pedis un `vector<vector<int>>` vas a obtener un arreglo de arreglos de enteros, i.e. un arreglo bidimensional, eso es lo que esta pasando en la primer linea.
En la segunda invocamos el metodo `push_back` el cual agrega un elemento al final del vector, como `miVector` es del tipo `vector<vector<int>>` el primer push back crea un objeto `vector<int>` y lo agrega.
La tercer linea contiene el segundo `push_back`, el cual actua sobre `miVector[0]` que es la primer fila de nuestro arreglo bidimensional y tiene el tipo `vector<int>`, o sea que acepta elementos `int`, por lo que agregamos simplemente el numero 1.
De esta forma terminamos teniendo un vector bidimensional de enteros que tiene una fila y una columna, con el numero 1 en su unica posicion.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo le hago un `push_back` a un array bidimensional ya definido?

De ninguna manera, porque **no se puede**. La función [`push_back` pertenece a contenedores como la lista, vector, string o deque entre otras](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=push_back) y tú no estás trabajando con nada de eso, estás trabajando con:

```
int A[6][6];
```

Que es una formación<sup>1</sup> bidimensional de enteros (`int`) cuyo tamaño está fijado en tiempo de compilación.

Por lo tanto **no puedes hacer un `push_back` a una formación bidimensional ya definida** porque las formaciones no tienen la función `push_back` y su tamaño está prefijado por lo tanto no puede crecer.

#### Propuesta

Tienes otra manera de conseguir tu objetivo, usa la clase `std::array` combinada con un contenedor (por ejemplo `std::vector`):

```
using Fila = std::array<int, 6>;
using Tabla = std::vector<Fila>;

Tabla tabla
{//  0  1  2  3  4  5
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // 0
    {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, // 1
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, // 2
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, // 3
    {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, // 4
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, // 5
};
```

Con el código anterior podrás insertar (`push_back`) filas así:

```
tabla.push_back({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});
```

O así:

```
Fila f;
f[0] = 1;
f[4] = 1;
tabla.push_back(f);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando <kbd>[aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5oYId1wC4ATZbVvs)</kbd>.

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o, en inglés, *array*.